# How to change the background color of tui using python dialog

Tags: python, dialog, tui

I am creating an application that needs some initial setup parameters. I wanted to build a Terminal User Interface in python to give a nicer input option to my users. I am using this library that is found at http://pythondialog.sourceforge.net/

Everything works great and suites my needs from the functionality standpoint. I would like to chnage the background color of the terminal though. Currently, it is bright blue, and I don't like that color. I have searched their documentation located at http://pythondialog.sourceforge.net/doc/ to no avail. How would one go about modifying the background color?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you have to tell dialog to use an rc file in order to customize the color theme. Create a sample file with:

```
dialog --create-rc /path/to/output/file
```

This file will contain parameter assignments such as:

```
# Dialog box color
dialog_color = (BLACK,WHITE,OFF)

# Dialog box title color
title_color = (BLUE,WHITE,ON)

# Dialog box border color
border_color = (WHITE,WHITE,ON)

# Active button color
button_active_color = (WHITE,BLUE,ON)
```

Customize it to your liking, then you have two options to make pythondialog tell dialog to use this file:

- use the `DIALOGRC` keyword argument in the [Dialog constructor](https://pythondialog.sourceforge.io/doc/Dialog_class_overview.html#dialog.Dialog.__init__);
- set the `DIALOGRC` environment variable to point to your rc file (for instance, in the shell from which your program is started).

If you develop a nice color theme, please send it to the dialog maintainer (preferably; cf. [dialog's home page](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/dialog.html)) or to the pythondialog mailing list so that it can benefit other users.